# How to get links in an iframe I don't control to open in parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is this even possible?

## Background

I have a page that's basically just a logo and an iframe.

I have complete control over the parent page and can use whatever tricks I want (html, javascript, php, etc.).

The page in the iframe, however, is a third party page that I have very little control over. I can use no javascript, no css, I can't even modify any links. All I can do is modify some text.

## Problem

I only need the logo on the initial page. Once the user logs in or clicks to a different page, I want that new page to open in the parent window. I know about target="_top" and target="_parent", but those won't help me because I have no real access to the links in the iframe.

## Question

Is there any attribute I can put on the iframe or javascript I can use in the parent page that will force new pages in the iframe to load in the parent window?

Comment: _"Is this even possible?"_ - **no** - it would be a violation of the cross-origin policy.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, though I'm not sure how it would create a security problem. It would only move their session to the parent window, which still wouldn't give the original parent page any access to any data that was within the iframe or the following page.

Comment: @Dai, if you're sure of your answer, would you mind submitting it as an actual answer that I can accept? It does answer my question, and I think having a clear, accepted answer would be useful to future users with this same problem.